# include <time.h>,an error occurred at the start

Tags: c, varnish-vcl

I use following code in `default.vcl`

```
C{#include <time.h>}C
```

an error occurred at the start.

```
Message from C-compiler:  
./vcl.TfBe17Rg.c:429:21: time.h: No such file or directory  
./vcl.TfBe17Rg.c:430:23: string.h: No such file or directory  
Running C-compiler failed, exit 1
```

Comment: @BartłomiejSemańczyk Do you have some evidence that a period was missing?

Comment: @EJP, no sorry, by mistake:(

Answer (score 0):

```
C{
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
}C
```

Try with the `sys/time.h`, it should work.